# FORMAT function dos not work for all numbers in a column?

Tags: mysql

I came accross situation when FORMAT function doesn't seem to work on all numbers in a column. Here's what I get:

```
Margin, %
----------------
NULL
210.3
15.899999999999999
NULL
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(profit/sales*100,1) as 'Margin, %' FROM table1
```

How do I force 1 digit after decimal point on all the vallues in a column?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, please add sample data and table definition as text to the question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either, but I copied it from the output from my big dataset. profit column is of type float, while sales is of type decimal there. Are there any other guaranteed ways to convert to desired format? Maybe by converting to text first, then back to decimal. Will try that.